# NEO4j Cypher query returning distinct value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

hello guys I am new to cypher query and I want to restrict duplicate values in my result

the query is

```
match (ee:Personal {id:"id"})-[:Friend]->(fr),
 (fr)-[:Friend]->(fr2),
 (fr2)-[:Friend]->(friend:Personal),
 (friend)-[:Works]->(comp:Company) 

where comp.name=~".*name.*" 
and not friend.id="id" 
and not (friend)-[:Friend]-(fr) 
and not (friend)-[:Friend]-(ee) 
and not (fr2)-[:Friend]-(ee) 

optional match (comp)-[:Position]->(pos), 
 (friend)-[:Position]->(pos)  
optional match (friend)-[:Location]->(loc) 

return distinct  friend.name,  comp.name
```

but i get duplicate values as there are multiple node properties in return statemnt. If I return only one property then its fine. but i want distinct friends

Answer (score 26):

Distinct works on the whole row, if you want to return distinct friends per company, do:

```
return comp.name, collect(distinct friend.name)
```